# IntelliJ IDEA Vim emulator's regex behaviour with newlines

Tags: regex, vim, intellij-idea, ideavim

For example, to transform:

```
List(
  User(1)
```

into:

```
UserQuery ++= List(
  User(1)
```

where the `User` is matched and used in forming `UserQuery`.

I've had some difficulty getting newlines in regex to work with IntelliJ's Vim emulator (at the bottom of the editor window, after pressing  and `:`).  There's no ^v like in ordinary Vim. :/

IntelliJ IDEA version: 14.1.3 (first time I've tried this in IntelliJ IDEA and so I don't know if this is a new issue.)
Platform: Mac OS X 10.10.2 (Yosemite)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found the following to work.

To match: use `\n`. To substitute in: use `\r`.

That is, `\n` doesn't work in substitution, `\r` doesn't work in pattern.  This regex works:

```
s/List(\n\( *\)\(\w*\)/\2Query ++= List(\r\1\2/
```